# Independently auto fade UITableView rows starting with the bottom row

Tags: swift, uitableview

Examples of row deletion usually implement `textFieldDidEndEditing` or some other gesture / user input method.

My version of an auto-deletion feature is to use animateWithDuration with alpha. It's simple and looks good.

The challenge is I would like to do this ***automatically*** via `NSTimer` or `animateWithDuration` **independently of any user scrolling and user input**. Just a simple fade-out starting with the newest bottom row and have it stay alpha 0 as it moves up the table.

Currently you don't see any rows when you open the app because the rows have already faded out. This is good. The problem occurs every time a user sends a new posts all the "invisible" rows appear again starting at alpha 1 and then all fade out together.

I need the previous rows above to stay at alpha 0 with only the new bottom row having alpha 1 then it fades away to alpha 0.

Is it because I need to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`instead? Or do I need to use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method?

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! CHEFTALKRecipeViewCell

let recipe = recipes[indexPath.item]

if recipe.posterId == posterId {
    cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    // STEP 1
    cell.contentView.alpha = 1

} else {
    // do something
}

return cell
}

// STEP 2
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0) {
    cell.contentView.alpha = 0
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As much as I understand your problem is that all cells animate. Even the ones at the top.

If so, you can retrieve `-visibleCells` from UICollectionView and start animation if only their position is at the bottom of the screen.